# PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException on SharePoint Online CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, csom

I am trying to write a simple Console Application in .NET using the CSOM object model.

I write the following code (omitted the client context declaration and the authentication parts from below):

```
var lib = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("A");

context.Load(sdf);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

However, when I debug the code and examine the "lib" object, all the properties have a `PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException`. What's the correct way to write code to not get that error?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What is "sdf"?

Add this line `context.Load(lib);` into your code before `context.ExecuteQuery();`, compare the results.

With the `Load(lib)`, it informs the client object model to load the information of SP.List object when the application calls the ExecuteQuery method.

Here is demo to connect to SharePoint Online and get list/library by title:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.Security;

namespace TestGetFiles
{
    class Program
    {


        private class Configuration
        {
            public static string ServiceSiteUrl = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/<site>";
            public static string ServiceUserName = "admin@tenant.onmicrosoft.com";
            public static string ServicePassword = "<password>";
        }

        static ClientContext GetonlineContext()
        {
            var securePassword = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in Configuration.ServicePassword)
            {
                securePassword.AppendChar(c);
            }
            var onlineCredentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(Configuration.ServiceUserName, securePassword);
            var context = new ClientContext(Configuration.ServiceSiteUrl);
            context.Credentials = onlineCredentials;
            return context;
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)  
        {  
            var clientContext=GetonlineContext();  
            List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("<library>"); 
            var fileName = "test.docx";
            CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.ViewXml =
               @"<View>
                       <Query>
                       <Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /><Value Type='File'>" + fileName + @"</Value></Eq></Where> 
                       </Query> 
                       <ViewFields><FieldRef Name='FileRef' /><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /></ViewFields> 
               </View>";​
            ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
            clientContext.Load(listItems);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            foreach (ListItem oListItem in listItems)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(oListItem["FileRef"].ToString());
                //do something
            }       

        }
    }
}
```

Some helpful References:

[Connecting Office 365 / SharePoint Online Site Using CSOM (Client Object Model)](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/office-365-sharepoint-online-connecting-office-365-sharepoint-online-site/)

[How to Connect SharePoint Online site using CSOM](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/office365-how-to-connect-sharepoint-online-site-using-csom)